# React hooks - send updated value from child to parent component when using onChange and prop of child toghether

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I've two components - Parent and Child using `react hooks`.

Here, `collected` is a state variable of parent component. And it's being passed to `TenderInput` component.

```
const handleBlur = (val) => {
    console.log('::: handleBlur :::');
    console.log(val);
    setCollected(Number(val).toFixed(2));
  }

<TenderedInput
 default={collected}
 focus={focusInput}
 // onChange={handleBlur}
 />
```

In `TenderInput`

```
const TenderedInput = (props) => {
  const [tendered, updateTendered] = useState(props.default);

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    const val = convertToCurrency(event.target.value);
    updateTendered(val);
    // props.onChange(event.target.value); this line causes an issue when I try to update state of parent with this call
  }

  return (
    <div className="collected__amount">
      <input
        type="text"
        className="form__input"
        value={tendered}
        onChange={event => handleChange(event)}
        onFocus={event => event.currentTarget.select()}
        autoFocus={props.focus}
        tabIndex="2"
      />
    </div>
  )
}
```

`TenderInput`'s `textbox` and it's `onChange` event is working fine and updating `tendered` state of `TenderInput` component. But at the same I need to update parent's state. Now, `collected` is in parent and if I add `props.onChange(event.target.value)`, `collected` is getting updated every time we enter something in textbox and re-renders the component and doesn't allow to enter the correct value.

I even tried to add `props.onChange(event.target.value)` in `onBlur` on `TenderInput`'s textbox but then I need to click on a button twice to make it work.

**How do I handle updating child component's state and at the same time update parent's state? **

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are going to need the same value of the state for both (parent and child), then why don't you declare and manage that state from the parent instead of from the child? So in your parent component you would have:

```
const [tendered, updateTendered] = useState(props.default);

const handleChange = (event) => {
  const val = convertToCurrency(event.target.value);
  updateTendered(val);
}

return (
  <TenderedInput
    tendered={tendered}
    focus={focusInput}
    onChange={handleChange}
  />
)
```

And in your child you would have:

```
const TenderedInput = (props) => {
  return (
    <div className="collected__amount">
      <input
        type="text"
        className="form__input"
        value={props.tendered}
        onChange={event => props.handleChange(event)}
        onFocus={event => event.currentTarget.select()}
        autoFocus={props.focus}
        tabIndex="2"
      />
    </div>
  )
}
```

So this way you will have the state managed from the parent instead of the child, and both will be handled simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply pass the **parentStateSetter** function into the child component as props and update the state externally from the child component,make the onChangeHandler in child component update both parent and child state

```
handlechange = (e) => {setChildState(...);setParentState(...)}
```

just pass the textfield value into both stateSetters and it will update both states as you want.